# how to create start and end date in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
Product component lead time
mobile  batteries  2days
mobile  charger    4 days
charger cable      2 days
charger adapter     2 days
```

I want to create a start date and the due date for example adapter start date should be started by today and due date =start date+ lead time. for product mobile and component charger's start date is equal to the due date of the charger cable
how can I implement this logic in python

Comment: Can you show `due date` column after implemnted your logic?

Comment: yes I want a show of column of the start date, due date

Comment: I think what are exactly dates.

Comment: start date of adpter should be today and rest of the components's start date is considerd according lead time.

Comment: So `due date` column is filled by `2021-03-14, 2021-03-16, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-14` ?

Comment: Product component lead time startdate  duedate
mobile  batteries  2days     16-3-2021   18-3-2021
mobile  charger    4 days   14-3-2021   18-3-2021
charger cable      2 days    12-3-2021   14-3-2021
charger adapter     2 days  12-3-2021 12-3-2021+2(leadtime)

Comment: Why is `mobile  batteries` for `startdate` `16-3-2021` ? How is count it?

Comment: because firstly done batteries component.after the batteries component done then only will start mobile batteries. and we should maintain our due date same for the same product that's why

Answer (score 0):

The approach would be to use the `pandas` and `datetime` module and increment the number of days from the lead time column. But to use the number of days as a number, one would have to extract it out from the string (by removing the 'days', removing all whitespaces and converting the resultant to integer). Following is the implementation in code!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {
    "Product":['mobile', 'mobile', 'charger', 'charger'],
     "component":['batteries', 'charger', 'cable', 'adapter'],
     "lead time":['2days', '4 days', '2 days', '2 days'] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['start date'] = datetime.datetime.now().date()
df['due date'] = ''
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  n = int(((df['lead time'][i]).replace("days","")).strip())
  df['due date'][i] = datetime.datetime.now().date()+datetime.timedelta(days=n)
```

The resulting dataframe would be -

```
    Product component   lead time   start date  due date
0   mobile  batteries   2days       2021-03-12  2021-03-14
1   mobile  charger     4 days      2021-03-12  2021-03-16
2   charger cable       2 days      2021-03-12  2021-03-14
3   charger adapter     2 days      2021-03-12  2021-03-14
```

Comment: mobile charger's start date should be equal to the due date of charger-cable

Comment: Have u any idea about this,I think it's definitely be by recursion